# Maven showing incorrect version

Tags: maven

I am learning the basics of maven and am using apache-maven-3.2.2. I have added the M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME environment variables. However when I run the command `mvn -version` it says the maven version is 2.2.1. Following is the result:

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-07 00:46:01+0530)
Java version: 1.8.0_25
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "amd64" Family: "dos"
```

Comment: Can u show what you added for M2_Home and MAVEN_HOME

Comment: I had this same error, and had added the `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin` to the `PATH`. So `echo %MAVEN_HOME%` gave me the correct directory, but `mvn -v` gave me the wrong version.


Turns out, I had the bin of the other maven version ALSO in my PATH, but listed out `C:/user/apache-maven-.../`` and I missed it. Issue was fixed after I deleted it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have only one global variable for setting maven home directory location. Also update the same variable's bin location (`%M2_HOME%\bin`)in System Path variable

Comment: M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME point to D:\Maven and i have added it in the system path as %M2_HOME%\bin;

Comment: Remove your MAVEN_HOME. It is redundant

Comment: Also close your current cmd prompt window..open a new one and give mvn -version

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Windows PATH isn't pointing at the correct maven version.  From [the Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/windows-prerequisites.html):

> You run Maven by invoking a command-line tool: mvn.bat from the bin
>   directory of the Maven. To do this conveniently,
>   c:\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin must be in your PATH, just like the J2SE SDK
>   commands. You can add directories to your PATH in the control panel;
>   the details vary by Windows version.

You'll need to change that path to point to the 3.2.2 version you have installed.

However, it's also worth noting that the maven command is `mvn`, not `maven`.  I guess that could be a typo on your part, but if not you should make sure you're using the right command (`mvn -version`)